# Django: collectstatic works but doesnt find the correct static folder

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I'm trying to run my django site in deployment mode with `DEBUG=False`. In fact when i do a `python manage.py collectstatic` it will collect all static files into my  folder `/mysite/static`. But when i load my homepage my static files wont load `Not Found` occurs.

My Django version is **1.10.4**
Here is my STATIC ROOT definition and urls folder:

In **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") (i tried also just only 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/mysite/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

my **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [   
    url(r'', include('mysite.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I notice that is not assuming my collectstatic folder instead is considering the static file in app folder.

doing `python manage.py findstatic mysite/js/javascript.js`

```
Found 'app/js/javascript.js' here:
/home/user/mysite/app/static/app/js/javascript.js
```

Well, once that `DEBUG=False` it should give something like:

```
 /home/user/mysite/static/app/js/javascript.js
```

Comment: Did you configure your webserver to serve `yourdomain.com/static/` from the `STATIC_ROOT` folder?

Comment: well i think that is not necessary because i have already start a new django site and it works all ok.. without `yourdomain.com/static/`

Comment: @MrMartin cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score 2):

At production server, your nginx or apache should serve the static files. When Debug = False, django stops serving the static files. Please share your nginx settings, I can help you out there...

For more info, check [this link](http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your production setup, you may have to set up your Apache or nginx config file to point to static content.  For example, in nginx, you can add a "location /static/ {...}" entry, eg. something like this:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        allow all;
        alias /your/base/dir/here/.../mysite/static/;
    }
    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```